# rails migration : check existence of multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I have a company table and I want to check the existence of multiple column to remove them.

```
class RemoveSettingsReportColumnsFromCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    if column_exists?( :companies, :automatically_send_report ) && column_exists?( :companies, :time_limit_for_sending_report ) && column_exists?( :companies, :report_fragment_color ) && column_exists?( :companies, :display_default_avatar )
      remove_column :companies, :automatically_send_report, :boolean
      remove_column :companies, :time_limit_for_sending_report, :integer
      remove_column :companies, :report_fragment_color, :string
      remove_column :companies, :display_default_avatar, :boolean
    end
  end
end
```

As you see there is a redundancy of use of the function **column_exists**, and I want to better organize and reduce my code, can some one tell if there is a way to use **column_exists** in other way, and give it as parameters all columns I want to remove ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simplify it a little bit. First of all - you can list all attributes using `Company.attribute_names`. It will return an array. So you can do something like:

```
if (%w[automatically_send_report time_limit_for_sending_report report_fragment_color display_default_avatar] - Company.attribute_names).empty?
  # migration code
end
```

Another solution, a little bit prettier (IMO) is:

```
if Company.attribute_names.to_set.superset?(Set['automatically_send_report', 'time_limit_for_sending_report', 'report_fragment_color', 'display_default_avatar'])
  # migration code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FIELDS = %i[automatically_send_report time_limit_for_sending_report
            report_fragment_color display_default_avatar].zip(
         %i[boolean integer string boolean]).to_h

def up
  FIELDS.keys.each do |col|
    remove_column(:companies, col) if column_exists?(:companies, col)
  end
end

def down
  FIELDS.each do |col, type|
    add_column(:companies, col, type) unless column_exists?(:companies, col)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Aleksei , but you forgot to put column type ! can you look again plz

Comment: [`remove_column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_column) does not require type, it’s effectively ignored even if given.

Comment: aha I see , but just a question :  isn't required when I want to do a rollback  ?

Comment: I have no idea how `change` handles this. I usually go with `up` and `down` for clarity. Updated an answer.